# WebAPI Controller reuse

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Let's say I have the following ApiController in my ASP.NET WebAPI Application:

```
class MyApiController : ApiController
{
    private string str;

     [HttpGet]
    public string SetStr(string str)
    {
        this.str = str;
        MaybeSleep(); // Some executions take longer, some don't.
        return this.str;
    }
}
```

(Reality is a bit more complicated, but this should be all that matters)

This is running fine in my environment and certain others, always returning the input value, even under heavy server load.

In two environments, however, str *sometimes* "magically" changes between set and return, even without too much server load. However, it always changes to values that were sent to the server around that time, just not always the ones sent in this request.

So, my questions are:

- Is ApiController reuse a behaviour that I just have to expect, or should a new ApiController be created, used and destroyed for every single request the server processes?
- Is this behaviour depending on ASP.NET version, IIS version and/or a Web.config setting?
- Is there documentation about the behaviour of private ApiController variables available from Microsoft?
- Or is this possibly a known bug in a certain .NET or ASP.NET version?

Comment: A new controller is created for each request so unless you have a shared resource interfering, this should be isolated.

Comment: I am pretty sure your example is wrong and does not reflect the real world situation. First of all I don't think controllers can be reused in that way (if they could I'd be really worried about some of my projects). Second reused or not you are just returning the argument. You are using the field as a kind of local variable.

Comment: Unless you are using the same ApiController reference for multiple calls. (Like creating a global Controller and calling the method, which will rewrite the attribute for every call), you should be good to go. And as said by Stilgar, this is probably not the whole situation and there is probably more to it then it seems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A request should not modify the state of a controller. From the entry method to any other methods called, you can pass parameters as needed, so there's no need to modify the controller object itself according to the request.

If there's some state that you need to maintain throughout the request that you can't pass through parameters to other methods, the best place to do that is on the `HttpContext` since that is always specific to the request. (Even then that scenario probably isn't too common.)

Instead of this:

```
public string SetStr(string str)
{
    this.str = str;
    MaybeSleep(); // Some executions take longer, some don't.
    return this.str;
}
```

this:

```
public string SetStr(string str)
{
    HttpContext.Items["str"] = str; //I'd declare a constant for "str"
    MaybeSleep(); 
    return HttpContext.Items["str"];
}
```

Comment: Do you have a link to back up your first sentence? It seems to contradict the other answer as well as the three comments.

Comment: No, I don't. I also don't disagree with the other comments at all - my answer is complementary. There's no rule that says a controller can't take on some state from a request, but it goes against the grain. If your controllers are stateless then you don't have to worry about whether or not they're reused.

Answer (score 1):

> Is ApiController reuse a behaviour that I just have to expect, or
>   should a new ApiController be created, used and destroyed for every
>   single request the server processes?

When a request is received, a new controller instance is created by ControllerFactory or DependencyResolver.

Basically, main thread creates a controller instance, and then the same instance is shared between multiple threads until the request is completed.

*The rest of the question is not relevant anymore since the first assumption is not correct.*

Ideally, if you execute long running process, you want to use a scheduler so that it will not freeze the UI.

You can read more at Scott Hanselman's blog - [How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)